# EF:CF Many-To-Many in a Detached Context

Tags: entity-framework, serialization, ef-code-first

I have two objects with a many to many relationship, let's call them Book and Category. The standard thing to do in Entity Framework - Code First would be to map them together and put a navigation property on either side, which I have done. I am working in a detached context, so I need to serialize my objects. So if I have two `Book` objects and three `Category` objects, one of which is shared by the two `Book` objects, do I suffer a performance loss by serializing the `Book` objects as they are by serializing the shared `Category` twice? Would it be beneficial performance-wise to serialize my `Book` objects and `Category` objects separately and rebuild the relationship post-serialization?

I suppose it might depend on the serializer. If anyone has any other tips on the best method to go about this, I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use serialization with reference tracking (you must do it anyway if you have navigation properties from `Book` to `Category` and from `Category` to `Book` otherwise you will get circular reference exception). Once you use this serialization each your entity will be serialized only once.

Comment: The thing is I only use one navigation property, so it's one sided, so no circular references.

Comment: But the point is still the same. If you want to avoid duplicities you need serialization process which is able to track dependencies. What serialization are you going to use?