# Serialization of Entity Framework objects with One to Many Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.5

I am attempting to use EF with Code First and the Web API.  I don't have any problems until I get into serializing Many-to-Many relationships.  When I attempt to execute the following web api method below I get the following error message:

```
public class TagsController : ApiController
{

        private BlogDataContext db = new BlogDataContext();

        // GET api/Tags
        public IEnumerable<Tag> GetTags()
        {
            return db.Tags.AsEnumerable();
        }
}
```

I get the following error:

> 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tag_FF17EDDE6893000F7672649A39962DB0CA591C699DDB73E8C2A56203ED7C7B6D'
>   with data contract name
>   'Tag_FF17EDDE6893000F7672649A39962DB0CA591C699DDB73E8C2A56203ED7C7B6D:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

I have read some SO articles ([article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315311/using-navigation-properties-in-entity-framework-code-first), [article 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071118/efcf-many-to-many-in-a-detached-context)) that the fix is to add the following attribute:

> [DataContract (IsReference=true)]

but this has had no effect.  Also using [IgnoreDataMember] does not have an effect.  The only option that does seem to work is to set Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled to false.  Is this my only option?  Am I missing something?

***Sample POCO objects:***

**Tag**

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Tag
{
        public Tag()
        {
            this.Blogs = new HashSet<Blog>();
        }

        [Key]
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

**Blog**

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same issue, and I found the only solution is as you, and Erik Philips, has said. To turn proxy creation off. The reason `IgnoreDataMember` doesn't have an effect is because the issue is with the proxy generation, not the serialisation of the `ICollection` of `Tags`.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve it?
When i disable proxy creation then i can't get the values of the parent, which i need it. plz help me.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

When you see an object like:

> System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Tag_FF17EDDE6893000F7672649A39962DB0CA591C699DDB73E8C2A56203ED7C7B6D

It is a runtime EF Generated version of a *proxy* to what would normally be considered a POCO object.

Entity Framework has created this object because it tracks when the objects has changed so when you call `.SaveChanges()` it can optimize what to do.  The downfall of this is that you aren't actually using the specific object you defined, thus Data Contracts and Frameworks (Json.net) cannot use them as they would your original POCO object.

To Prevent EF from returning this object you have two choices (ATM):

First, [Try turning off Proxy object creation on your DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577852/209259).

```
DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

This will completely disable the create of Proxy objects for every query to the specific DbContext.  (This does not affect the *cached* object in the ObjectContext).

Secondly, use **EntityFramework 5.0+** with [AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx)
(ProxyCreationEnabled is still available in EF 5.0 as well)

You should also be able to

```
DbContext.Persons.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
DbContext.Persons.
  .Include(i => i.Parents)
  .AsNoTracking()
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Instead of *globally* disabling proxy creation for the DbContext, this only turns it off per query.  (This *DOES* affect the *cached* object in the ObjectContext, it is not cached)

Comment: The problem is that in order for Entity Framework to track changes, when you ask it for an Instance, it provides a wrapped instance that has triggers for change tracking.  The wrapped instance almost always is unable to be serialized.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I am sorry but i can't understand the solution, so i should not disable proxy creation? or i should?
and then i should use dbcontext.class.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault()?
What does it do exactly?

Comment: @Dark_Knight Updated my answer, I hope it has the details you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Had to use this with EF6 as well - you saved me a bunch of frustration!

Comment: @ErikPhilips What would be the consequences if I disable the ProxyCreation globally ??

Comment: @Zakawat sounds like a great question to ask.  Use the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and ask the question :)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to leave proxy creation inteact, and found that using the `ProxyDataContractResolver` seemed to resolve the issue for me. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee705457(v=vs.100).aspx) for a reference on how to use it in wcf, which isn't exactly WebAPI, but should get you going along the right path.

Comment: Do you mind explaining to me how to use ProxyDataContractResolver to sereialize poco entities? The only example I managed to find involved WCF and I couldn't figure out how it works.