# The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC5 app, and I have included WebAPI inside it. I tested it and it worked fine for simple string and stuff. Then I tried to do something like this:

```
public Business Get(string id)
{
     return db.Businesses.Where(b => b.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And I got the above mentioned error. Please note that Business is a custom type that I created in my models folder. In my `WebApiConfig` file I have something like this:

```
var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
formatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Any idea how to solve the problem?

**EDIT:**

Some more of the error message:

> Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Business_32C47B90BA261D075748CEC009DA52F8C6D893134F8D33848A7F856F76F50D55'
>   with data contract name
>   'Business_32C47B90BA261D075748CEC009DA52F8C6D893134F8D33848A7F856F76F50D55:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are
>   using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to
>   the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute
>   attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the
>   serializer.System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException

Comment: The exception message isn't enough. Does the content of the exception go into detail of what failed?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I included some more text.

Comment: If you're sending something over WebAPI, it needs to be serializable.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077328/serialization-of-entity-framework-objects-with-one-to-many-relationship). I think it should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I simply needed to include this line of code:

```
DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```