# ContractResolver per Controller and Entity Framework DynamicProxies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

When overriding the [ContractResolver Per Controller](https://www.coreysmith.co/sitecore-and-web-api-set-custom-contractresolver/) and responding with EF code first models with `DynamicProxies`

```
public virtual ICollection<Dealer>
```

I get the following error:

> Der Typ 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Category_3A79660F329089EEB63C385A2604922D659127A759AE76F676297AF7DC53A144'
>   mit dem Datenvertragsnamen
>   'Category_3A79660F329089EEB63C385A2604922D659127A759AE76F676297AF7DC53A144:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'
>   wird nicht erwartet. Verwenden Sie ggf. einen DataContractResolver,
>   wenn Sie DataContractSerializer verwenden, oder fügen Sie alle
>   unbekannten Typen statisch der Liste der bekannten Typen hinzu,
>   beispielsweise mithilfe des KnownTypeAttribute-Attributs oder indem
>   Sie sie zur Liste der bekannten Typen hinzufügen, die an das
>   Serialisierungsprogramm übergeben wird.

The only thing I'm changing in the initialize method is:

```
controllerSettings.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Running the same code in the OWIN startup class works perfect.

I do not want to solve this problem by just disabling EF proxies:

```
DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Without that change everything works fine, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The 'ObjectContent\`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150187/the-objectcontent1-type-failed-to-serialize-the-response-body-for-content-typ)

Comment: This would work - but just by disabling the EF proxy classes. I want to keep them _but_ be able to serialize them.